# Custom Kendo Vue Grid Wrapper Column Template Using kendo-grid columns Attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following template that I would like to use to render the contents of a Kendo grid wrapper cell:

```
<template>
   <span>
      Template Rendered: {{ templateArgs.name }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'template1',
  data () {
    return {
      templateArgs: {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am able to do this using kendo-grid-column elements as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <kendo-grid :data-source="datasource">
          <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name" :template="itemTemplate"></kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Grid, GridColumn } from '@progress/kendo-grid-vue-wrapper'
import Template from './Template.vue'

var itemTemplate = Vue.component(Template.name, Template)

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
   components: {
       'kendo-grid': Grid,
       'kendo-grid-column': GridColumn
   },
   methods: {
        itemTemplate: function (e) {
          return {
            template: itemTemplate,
            templateArgs: e
          }
        }
    },
  data () {
    return {
        datasource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I would like to use the kendo-grid columns attribute instead, as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <kendo-grid :data-source="datasource" :columns="columns">
    </kendo-grid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Grid, GridColumn } from '@progress/kendo-grid-vue-wrapper'
import Template from './Template.vue'

var itemTemplate = Vue.component(Template.name, Template)

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
   components: {
       'kendo-grid': Grid,
       'kendo-grid-column': GridColumn
   },
   methods: {
        itemTemplate: function (e) {
          return {
            template: itemTemplate,
            templateArgs: e
          }
        }
    },
  data () {
    return {
        columns: [{ field: "name", title: "Name", template: this.itemTemplate }],
        datasource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Something is wrong with the code in the second case, though. Instead of rendering the cells using the template, I am getting [object Object] as the cell contents. What should I do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the columns property when using custom render templates is not supported by the Vue grid wrapper. Something similar can be done with a native grid, however.

Source: https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-kendo-grid-wrapper-column-template-using-kendo-grid-columns-attribute